# ImageMagick policy interpretation order: disable all coders, allow only one

Tags: imagemagick

the [policy documentation](https://www.imagemagick.org/source/policy.xml) for imagemagick isn't very broad unfortunately, so i wanted to know whether it is possible to disable all codecs except one. Is this possible? Maybe by rule interpretation order where the second policy overrules the first one like this:

```
<policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="*" />
<policy domain="coder" rights="read | write" pattern="jpeg" />
```

I can think of several possibilities for this:

- in the same file, second rule below first rule
- in different files according to the [configuration load order](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/resources.php)

It seems there is only the asterisk-globbing available in patterns, not other regex-style matching or negation (`pattern="not jpeg"` or something).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not attempt wildcard pattern matching, but be explicate about all coders. Luckily, ImageMagick's `identify` utility, and it can tell you all the coders available in the system's library.

```
identify -list Coder
```

Which you can run through awk/sed, and other one-liner utilities to generate a policy map.

```xml
<policymap>
    <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="BGR" />
    <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="BMP" />
    <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="BRAILLE" />
    <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="CALS" />
    <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="CMYK" />
    <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="DDS" />
    <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="DNG" />
    <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="DOT" />
    <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="EPT" />
    <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="FAX" />
    <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="FITS" />
    <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="GIF" />
    <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="GRADIENT" />
    <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="HTML" />
    <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="ICON" />
    <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="INLINE" />
    <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="JBIG" />
    <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="JP2" />
    <policy domain="coder" rights="read | write" pattern="JPEG" />
    <!-- ...  -->
    <!-- 
        Other coders omitted so folks don't copy-n-past, and assume "job-done"
      -->
</policymap>
```

And of course, repeat with `identify -list Format`, and `identify -list Delegate`.

**But why not a pattern?**

My argument is this. If you author a clever pattern today, what happens when business requirements change tomorrow? I imagine that the policy map will grow in complexity.

What happens if there's a revision in two years? Attempting to read & remember what the pattern is doing will take way more time then three key-stokes in [vim](/questions/tagged/vim).

Comment: thanks for the explanation! My reason for a wildcard deactivation was that there might be new coders added in the future which then are not deactivated automatically; which in turn might be a security issue.